# sendTransform() takes exactly 6 arguments (2 given)

Tags: ros, broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to run [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) in python code, but i got above error when i try to run it.
My python converted program of given tutorial is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Header
import tf
import geometry_msgs.msg
import math

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('state_publisher')

broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()   
rate = rospy.Rate(30) # 10hz 
M_PI = 3.145
degree = M_PI/180;

# robot state
tilt = 0 
tinc = degree 
swivel=0 
angle=0 
height=0 
hinc=0.005

# message declarations
t = geometry_msgs.msg.TransformStamped()
hello_str = JointState()
t.header.frame_id = "odom"
t.child_frame_id = "axis"

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    # update joint_state
    hello_str.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    hello_str.name = ['swivel','tilt','periscope']
    hello_str.position = swivel
    hello_str.velocity = tilt
    hello_str.effort = height

    t.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    t.transform.translation.x = math.cos(angle)*2
    t.transform.translation.y = math.sin(angle)*2
    t.transform.translation.z = .7
    #t.transform.rotation = tf.createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(angle+M_PI/2)
    t.transform.rotation = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, angle)
    # send the joint state and transform
    pub.publish(hello_str)
    broadcaster.sendTransform(t)

    # Create new robot state
    tilt += tinc
    if (tilt<-.5 or tilt>0):
       tinc *= -1
    height += hinc
    if (height>.2 or height<0):
      hinc *= -1
    swivel += degree
    angle += degree/4

    rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

How can i remove this, i am using ros indigo.
Even if i change that line with :

broadcaster.sendTransform((0.5,1.0,0),tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, angle+M_PI/2),rospy.Time.now(),"odom","axis")
Its not working. Than it shows error:

```
 field position must be a list or tuple type
[state_pub-2] process has died [pid 11654, exit co
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258017/sendtransform()-takes-exactly-6-arguments-(2-given)/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you might want to use the [sendTrasformMessage method](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/indigo-devel/tf/src/tf/broadcaster.py#L74)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0